# VBA Macro find and replace value in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to search for a valu in column "C" and replace the values in colomn A and B. For example, find in col C "1234" replace in Col "A" Mike with M and in col "B" replace Smith with S
Also find in col C "9696" replace in Col "A" Paul with P and in col "B" replace Stanley with S

[image]

I tried this below, if a new line is added to my import csv file, i selects the wrong row.
Sub  testnamechange()
'
' testnamechange Macro
'

```
'
Columns("H:H").Select
Selection.Find(What:="211006851", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2 _
    , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Range("B12720").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "A"
Range("C12720").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "A"
Range("D12720").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "M"
Columns("H:H").Select
Range("H12710").Activate
Selection.Find(What:="211006853", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2 _
    , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Range("B12791").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "E"
Range("C12791").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "E"
Range("D12791").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "M"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ChDir "C:\SDK"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\SDK\update.csv", FileFormat _
    :=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out (based on your sample data):

```vb
Sub Tester()
    FindAndSet 1234, "M", "S"
    FindAndSet 9696, "P", "S"
End Sub

Sub FindAndSet(findThis, valB, valC)
    Dim m As Variant
    With ActiveSheet.Columns("A")
        m = Application.Match(findThis, .Cells, 0)
        If Not IsError(m) Then  'got a match?
            With .Cells(m).EntireRow
                .Columns("B").Value = valB  'replace values...
                .Columns("C").Value = valC
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```